# Parser error on Xpand: SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to SAXParserFactory

Tags: sax, xml-parsing, xerces, xpand

I am getting this dialog box when i am building my application with Xpand.

"**An internal error occurred during: "Analyzing accessible EMF metamodels for project my.generator.project".
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory"**

What is the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and [described my solution here](http://www.jevon.org/wiki/Could_not_open_the_editor%3a_SAXParserFactoryImpl_cannot_be_cast_to_SAXParserFactory).

Basically, this occurs when is more than one SAX parser in your current classpath heirarchy; e.g. the calling plugin requires a SAXParser but one has already been created in another plugin which cannot be accessed through the classpath.

**Solution:** You may have two Xerces plugins in your environment. Use the Plug-in Registry (Window > Show View > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Registry) to find out which plugins are causing this. In my case, I had two plugins which both contributed a `xerces.jar`.

Comment: Almost - it's not caused by two SAX parsers in the classpath, it's caused by two copies of the API classes. There should only be one.